# Handling "New Functionality" fly outs in XCUItest for iOS updates

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I have a set of XCUItests that exercise a bit of functionality in my app. Currently, I have the following function that pulls up a keyboard, types some stuff in, then taps "Search" (which is the equivalent in Enter in this context.

```swift
func clickSearchOnKeyboard(_ app: XCUIApplication) {
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Search"].waitForExistence(timeout: 10))
        app.textFields["SearchItemView.SearchTextFieldID"].clearAndEnterText(testData.productData.valid.styleColor)
        XCUIApplication().buttons["Search"].tap()
    }
```

However, after updating the simulators to iOS 13, this test will fail because now when the keyboard is first pulled up we get a "What's New" fly-out explaining the new swipe functionality.

[image: fly-out-ios]

I think I can just add an `If` clause to my test code to handle this the first time it pops up, but I'm wondering if anyone has found out a way to disable these sorts of things for simulator testing:

- Something in the `Init()` method that would disable "What's New" type of pop ups?
- Some clever function that could always intercept this event and click "Continue"?

EXTRA BONUS POINTS: These automated tests run as part of an automated pipeline. As part of that, an assumption is that these tests run against a completely brand new simulator set (so we can't reuse existing simulators). Specifically, we blow away simulators (using Erase All Contents & Settings) prior to every run. So whatever solution will need to be completely portable and require 0 manual intervention.

Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just testing for the dialog and dismissing it if it appears should be the best approach.

You could also launch an apple tool and trigger the popup after the erase & reset operation is complete as part of your initial tooling setup.

e.g.

1. xcrun simctl erase deviceuuid
2. xcodebuild test-without-building test name:DismissKeyboardTour destination=deviceuuid
3. xcodebuild test-without-building mytestsuite destination=deviceuuid

I would think you would only need to do this once per test suite run (eg all the tests)

Comment: This is probably the least worst solution. It's still reactive (ie if iOS 14 includes a change to app focus I would need to write something new) but at least it would work for any new keyboard change.

Comment: The problem is that Apple does not appear to allow us a setting to disable their tours, and they can add new ones at any moment. Perhaps a radar..

Answer (score 1):

You can run tests on clones of an already configured simulator (use `xcrun simctl clone ...`)

If you want to create simulators from scratch, then add a git repository in simulator folder, configure it as you like (skip keyboard onboarding in your case) and use `git status` to know what shall be changed in order to configure your simulators in scripts.

Detailed:

1. Create new simulator
2. Create a new git repository from its folder
3. Configure simulator the way you like
4. Watch changes in the simulator with git
5. Based on these changes add steps to your CI/CD runner script (prior test running)

Comment: Could you add some detail to your answer? I don't know what you mean by "use `git status` to know what shall be changed in order to configure your simulators in scripts`.

Do you mean that I would have to run git status prior to any testing to determine if an iOS change has been made?

Comment: Cons to this approach:
* Binary files stored in git 
* updating of binary files when you update to new os, 
* a new container needed for each device.

Comment: I do not suggest you keep simulators folder anywhere. I recommend using git in order to keep track of how changes in a simulator may have been repeated faster in scripts.

Comment: This actually doesn't help with my situation - I pretty much know when our simulators change so it's not a surprise. I'm just trying to figure out how to address this situation holistically and proactively rather than reactively each time I discover a new change